# Barplot in Pandas with Seaborn

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a barplot with only two values:

```
plot_data

           Free_Cashflow_Per_Share
Company 
FB              83.666667
GOOG           193.365079
```

I would like the bars to be separated and to be able to define the color of each bar.

My code is the following:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.barplot(data_plot)
```

Which returns the following plot:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add parameters `x`, `y` and `palette`:

```
sns.barplot(x=data_plot.index, 
            y=data_plot['Free_Cashflow_Per_Share'], 
            palette=['r','b'],
            data=data_plot)
```

Or:

```
sns.barplot(x='Company'
            y='Free_Cashflow_Per_Share', 
            palette=['r','b'],
            data=data_plot.reset_index())
```